# postgresql index with order

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there any way to create with postgresql an index on a field and make sure index returns results ordered by id DESC?

Thanks

Comment: No, add an ORDER BY to your SELECT if you want a specific order.

Comment: @jarlh it seems this can work CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (index_field NULLS LAST, id DESC);

Comment: Perhaps it does right now, with the current data, and the current query...

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY): *If the `ORDER BY` clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in the specified order. If `ORDER BY` is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce. (See ORDER BY Clause below.)* The only correct way to guarantee ordering is to specify `order by` clause

Comment: Also note that index doesn't return anything because it is a storage structure, not a query.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes store their entries in ascending order, If you are asking about if indexes can store their entries in descending order then the answer is **YES**.

You can add an ordered index by including the options ASC, DESC, NULLS FIRST, and/or NULLS LAST when creating the index; for example:

```
CREATE INDEX test2_info_nulls_low ON test2 (info NULLS FIRST);
CREATE INDEX test3_desc_index ON test3 (Col DESC NULLS LAST);
```

This means that a backward scan of an index in column Col produces output satisfying `ORDER BY Col DESC`

[Docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: Either I or you misunderstood OP's question. I _think_ OP asked if a DESC index always will make a query return the rows in that descending order.

Comment: Ahh it could be, then the question is not clear !

Comment: thanks guys. I'll test this and i'll let you know